# Mod_rewrite URLs for SEO

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, seo

I have my directories setup like so:

```
mywebsite/directory1/index.php
mywebsite/directory2/index.php
mywebsite/directory3/index.php
mywebsite/directory4/index.php
```

this is not SEO friendly. How can I use mod_rewrite to do the following:

```
mywebsite/directory1/
mywebsite/directory2/
mywebsite/directory3/
```

How can I make search engines crawl my site without the issues of having multiple index.php´s?

What are you professional suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Place this into your root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
#if your index.php is located in the root folder:
RewriteBase /
#or use that, if the path for your index.php is '/some/subfolder/index.php':
#RewriteBase /some/subfolder/

#rewriting only if the request file doesn't exists (you don't want to rewrite request for images or other existing files)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)? index.php?path=$1 [L]
```

After that, you can use the REQUEST_URI in your root index.php file:

```
var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

or you can use $_GET['path']:

```
var_dump($_GET['path']);
```

In your HTML and CSS, use absolute path for images and other resources (or better use full URL's):

```
<img src="/image/image.jpg" alt="image" />
```